# How to tell if page has been disposed using BuildContext

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I was wondering whether it is possible to tell whether a widget has been disposed using the stful widgets context.

```
randomFunction(BuildContext context) {

  //Pseudo code
  if (context.noLongerAlive) {
    ...Do Something
  }

}
```

The function is not within the stful widget it is external

Answer (score 0):

As a variant you could use `mount` property of `State` class. But I think it is not good idea. The `mount` is `true` when `State` is attached to `Widget`.

```dart
randomFunction(BuildContext context) {
  if(!mount) {
    // widget was dismounted so the behaviour 
    // of its context is unstable and unpredictable
  }
}
```

Basically the `dispose` method is enough to know if widget is dispose.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the existence of the Widget by key:

```
key.currentWidget != null
```

[image]

### Full source code for easy copy-paste

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _displayWidget = useState(false);
    final _widgetKey = useState(GlobalKey());
    final _checked = useState(false);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            _displayWidget.value
                ? Text('Yeah! I exist!', key: _widgetKey.value)
                : Text('Widget does not exist.'),
            const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _checked.value = false;
                _displayWidget.value = !_displayWidget.value;
              },
              child: Text('TOGGLE WIDGET'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            Divider(),
            const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _checked.value = true;
              },
              child: Text('CHECK WIDGET EXISTENCE'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
            Text(_checked.value
                ? 'Widget exists? ${_widgetKey.value.currentWidget != null}'
                : 'Click to check Widget existence.'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Solution using the BuildContext as the entry point

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _displayWidget = useState(false);
    final _widgetContext = useState<BuildContext>();
    final _checked = useState(false);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          if (_displayWidget.value)
            MyWidget(
              key: GlobalKey(),
              onInit: (context) => _widgetContext.value = context,
            ),
          const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _checked.value = false;
              _displayWidget.value = !_displayWidget.value;
            },
            child: Text('TOGGLE WIDGET'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          Divider(),
          const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _checked.value = true;
            },
            child: Text('CHECK WIDGET EXISTENCE'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 24.0),
          Text(_checked.value
              ? 'Widget exists? ${(_widgetContext?.value?.widget?.key as GlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>)?.currentWidget != null}'
              : 'Click to check Widget existence.'),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends HookWidget {
  final ValueChanged<BuildContext> onInit;

  const MyWidget({Key key, this.onInit}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    useEffect(() {
      onInit(context);
      return;
    }, []);
    return Text('My Widget');
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not answering the question, for the certain case I am using I need to use buildContext

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question. Check my update. I provide the same solution but using the `BuildContext` as an entry point. If it still does not reach your goals... then try to be more explicit about your requirements and use case.

Comment: Is it possible to know if the MyWidget is alive without a key